# kagnax/html-minifier grunt plugin how to use multiple targets

Tags: html, gruntjs, minify

I am trying to use html-minifier grunt plugin (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) and the documentation says we can use multiple targets; That is, we can specify different options for different build environment. In the below example 2 targets are configured 'dist' and 'dev'

```
    grunt.initConfig({
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
            files: {
                'dist/index.html': 'src/index.html'
            }
        },
        dev: {
            files: {
                'dist/index.html': 'src/index.html'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But my question is, while using grunt how can I instruct the plugin to use specific target? For example, for a production build I want to use "dist" target specified in plugin config.  I can do **grunt htmlmin** but it triggers 'dev' target only.

Comment: You can use the colon (`:`) notation to access each target. For instance  when running via the command-line you run  `grunt htmlmin:dist` and `grunt htmlmin:dev`. Within your _gruntfile.js_ you also use the colon notation without the `grunt` part, for instance: `grunt.registerTask('production', ['htmlmin:dist']);`. However it does seem odd that when you run `grunt htmlmin` it only triggers the `dev` target, typically that should trigger all targets, i.e. both `dist` and `dev`.

Comment: **Note** Your `files` object in `dist` and `dev` are both set to `'dist/index.html': 'src/index.html'` , you probably want `'dev/index.html': 'src/index.html'` in the `dev` task instead.